# Why can terminal uninstall itself?

Tags: command-line, package-management, process, xterm

[image: screenshot]

How does `apt-get remove xterm` go through? And after it's been uninstalled, `xterm` doesn't close and continues to function normally.

Is the `xterm` process cached in RAM whilst it is running?

Comment: To be exact, It's not really uninstalling itself - `apt-get` is uninstalling `xterm`, and has no idea that it somehow depends on an `xterm` process - so it's about "Why can xterm be uninstalled while running?". Nice question.

Comment: It's similar to how you can delete the hard disk while running the OS.

Comment: releated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356483/is-it-safe-to-recompile-an-executable-while-its-running

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Not quite.  The file is already open by the program.  Deleting the file ( and then replacing it with another version ) does not affect the running program because the original file is held open ( though without a name on disk to open it again ) until the program is done with it.  Only when all handles to the file are closed are its data blocks on disk released.  Until then the open file can be read and written just like normal -- the only change is that nobody else can open it since its name has been removed.

While parts of the program may have already been read into ram when it is deleted, they may still be discarded and re-read later, or new parts of the program that had not previously been executed can still be loaded from the deleted file.

Comment: This is the actual reason....this is also the reason why `rm -rf /` works.....

Comment: If you wanna use the word "works" to describe successfully screwing everything totally up. ;)  Interestingly, `rm -rf /` won't work if you try to run it a second time immediately afterwards ;)

Comment: I've often seen "/some/file/name (deleted)" in `lsof` output, and I know that is what a 'zombie' file looks like... but is there any way of saving the contents of such a file from disappearing when the last file handle dies?

Comment: @KilianFoth, if you can find a process that still has the file open, then you can copy it from /proc/$PID/fd/$ID to another file, but I can't seem to find a way to recover the file in place as all attempts at hard linking the file fail.

Comment: @KilianFoth If there is a file handle, then `root` might be able to create a name for it (and thus prevent deletion) by using the `linkat` system call. But executables and libraries are memory mapped, which doesn't require a file handle. I don't know of any way to get a handle on a file which only exists because it is memory mapped. Though executables can be accessed through `/proc` while they are running, so it's only libraries and other memory mapped files which might be beyond recovery. If you want more details about that, you should ask it as a separate question.

Comment: So, does that mean if we delete the file in some other way (not the conventional way which deletes only the inode and not the data), in which the data is also re-written by '0's then the process (console) wil stop working..

Comment: @kasperd, that's what I meant in my previous comment about attempts to hard link it fail... linkat gives -EXDEV.  I don't see why, but it does.

Comment: @haris I don't think the kernel would allow you to write to the executable while it is running.

Comment: @psusi That's interesting. I would not expect that if the new name you tried to give it is indeed on the same partition as the deleted one.

Comment: @thomasrutter no actually, `rm -rf /` doesn't work and hasn't for many years. See the 2nd line in the Description section of the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html). That's why GNU `rm` has the `--no-preserve-root` option. By itself, `/bin/rm -rf /` is completely harmless.

Comment: @terdon you probably meant to address that to heemayl, I was just making silly jokes about his comment

Answer (score 8):

> Is the `xterm` process cached in RAM whilst it is running?

Exactly. It's similar to the process that allows you to install updates to things while they're running without them crashing. And also why you have to restart services after you update them. Once something is running, its binary is in memory.

If it depends on other files (that aren't in a held "open" state) that are removed or replaced, that might cause issues but for something as discrete as `xterm`, that isn't an issue.

Comment: Not quite.. parts of the program are read into memory only when needed, and may be discarded at any time to free up memory for other uses, and so will need to be read in again later ( when the program tries to access those parts again ).

Comment: It's not necessarily in RAM. But files aren't actually deleted until they aren't open, including the xterm executable.

Comment: @immibis, hence, my answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is in fact a feature of how computers work: When a program is invoked it is indeed loaded into the memory and it works from there.

A file actually works in the same way. To avoid problems many files in UNIX-ish systems create locks.

The actual riddle is why you can't do such and similar things in Windows.

This feature is actually what allows you to update the whole system, including the programs that are active in your system. ;)

Comment: +1 for "the actual iddle is why you can't do such and similar things in Windows"